# How to assign a value to a non declared control in reactive form?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have't declared an email control in html file but i have declared it in my form group.
I want to set the email value that is receiving in the **customers** to the email control.

```
<form class="form-row" [formGroup]="form" >
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Email Report</label>
          <mat-radio-group class="mb-3 d-block" formControlName="emailReport"  (change)="emailReport = $event.value;emitDataAndValidity()">
              <mat-radio-button [checked]="!emailReport" value="false">No
              </mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button [checked]="emailReport" value="true">Yes
              </mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <label>Customers</label>
          <mat-select placeholder="--Select--" class="form-control" disableOptionCentering formControlName="name" >
              <mat-option [value]="customer.firstName+' '+customer.lastName" id="customer.id" *ngFor="let customer of customers.clientManager">
                  {{customer.firstName +' '+customer.lastName }}
              </mat-option>
              <mat-option [value]="customer.email" id="customer.id" *ngFor="let customer of customers.supervisor">
                  {{customer.firstName +' '+customer.lastName }}
              </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      </div>
        <div class="ml-md-auto col-md-3">
          <label>Type</label>
          <mat-select placeholder="--Select--" class="form-control" disableOptionCentering formControlName="type" >
            <mat-option value='DAILY'> DAILY </mat-option>
            <mat-option value='WEEKLY'> WEEKLY</mat-option>
            <mat-option value='MONTHLY'> MONTHLY </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        </div>
      </form>
```

a typescript file that is receiveing customer object

I have to dynamically the change the email field according to change in select-bar value

```
 @Input() customers;
// customers=[{firstName:'rishabh',lastName:'tripathi',email:'trishabh@gmail.com',type:"Daily"}]

ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          emailReport:[false,Validators.required],
          name : ['',Validators.required],
          email:[''],
          type: ['',Validators.required]
       },{updateOn: 'change'});

      this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value =>{
       console.log(value)

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handlingSubcription: Subscription
constructor() {
this.form = this.fb.group({
          emailReport:[false,[Validators.required]],
          name : ['',[Validators.required]],
          email:['',[]],
          type: ['',[Validators.required]]
 });
}

ngOnInit() {
this.handlingSubcription = this.form('name').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  if (this.customers[0].hasOwnProperty('email'))
   this.form('email').setValue('jhondoe@gmail.com');
  }
})

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.handlingSubcription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: this won't work if i change the value in select bar then hot will it update from array of objects

Comment: I edit my answer you can listen when value of the select change using the valueChanges of the formControl and apply some logic using "setValue" method when the value change

Comment: Remember handling the subscription observable to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <label>Customers</label>
      <mat-select placeholder="--Select--" class="form-control" disableOptionCentering formControlName="name" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
          <mat-option [value]="customer" id="customer.id" *ngFor="let customer of customers.clientManager">
              {{customer.firstName +' '+customer.lastName }}
          </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </div>
```

You can listen for event `selectionChange` on `mat-select`. And set the email value on the `email` form control.

```
onSelectionChange(customer) {
  this.form.get('email').setValue(customer.email);
}
```

Comment: i am receiving an event called Mat-selct which does not have any value of customer or customer field

Comment: you also need to set the [value]="customer" on you `mat-option`.